# Is there any way to protect a folder from other people?

Tags: python-3.x, password-protection, directory-structure, folder-permissions

I'm having some troubles with people getting in my folder. Is there any way to have a program that whenever I try to open a specific folder it asks for a password and won't let you see what's in that folder unless you have the password?

Comment: Why in the world would you insist on using Python? Did you just try searching for applications that do that specifically? Or the account system on the computer? Also, some context is important - why do these people have access to your computer?

Comment: Try cryptomator: https://cryptomator.org/

Comment: On what operating system? And why with Python instead of using the functionality of the OS itself?

Comment: I want use python because it's the language that i know better and I want to create a program, not just download. I know the esayest way it's to download it. But after all where is the fun? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to take advantage of the account system on your computer. Just make an account and password protect it. It will be like you have the whole computer to yourself. If you are unable to make an account of your own for some reason (I don't know the circumstances) i guess you could just throw everything in the folder into a 7zip. No one can get into one of those without a password.